# Overfull \hbox with showframe/nomarginpar (geometry package)

Tags: geometry, showframe, overfull

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperheight=240mm
  ,paperwidth=170mm
  ,top=30mm
  ,bottom=30mm
  ,inner=25mm %% left
  ,outer=30mm %% right
  ,headsep=10mm
  ,nomarginpar
  ,heightrounded
  ,verbose
  ,showframe
}

\begin{document}

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\clearpage

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\clearpage

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\end{document}
```

Compiling I get twice

```
Overfull \hbox (0.4pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
```

These overfulls only affect odd pages.

If I comment only the `showframe` option, no `Overfull \hbox...` occurs. Same thing if I comment only the `nomarginpar` option.

Needless to say, I have already consulted the `geometry` package documentation with no success.

Why does this happen?

Comment: You can also fix it using `\marginparwidth=1pt`.  I wonder if the overfull box comes from trying to draw the frame inside the marginpar area.